# Storyboard view resizing trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Full disclaimer- I'm pretty new to iOS. I created a tableview with custom cells using the storyboard with a navigation controller as the initial entry point, and my tableview as the navigation controller's root view. When I run the app in the simulator, it seems as though everything is oversized/zoomed in, though my storyboard looks like this: [image]

I've tried with iPad and iPhone and in both devices my story board doesn't pop up properly. I instantiate my root view controller thus:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//get a pointer to my main storyboard
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

//instantiate my nav controller + item controller through the storyboard
UINavigationController *nav = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navStoryBoard"];
ItemsViewController *ivs = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tableStoryBoard"];

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window = window;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
```

}

Why won't my tableView appear in the correct size when I run my app? Am I instantiating my views incorrectly?

Comment: First of all you don't need to write any single line of code in didFinishlaunching. because all setup done in story board

Comment: Are you using Autolayout. Add a simulator screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you are using Size classes (which is usually enabled by default). And hence the zoomed or scaled up behaviour.

If you are developing for a particular form factor, you may disable the "Use Size Class" property of the View Controller. More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

However, if you want your UI to be scalable on different form factors - you should keep this checked and use Autolayout constrains for your Table View. More details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html

Comment: thanks, I decided to code for just my iPhone and it worked fine!